# How to store many images in a model object? Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, structure, nsobject

I'm having some problem with my code structure in Objective-C.
I have a model-class (NSObject) called Item which stores a name and a description:

```
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name desc:(NSString *)desc
```

Then I have a model called ItemDoc which stores an image, and the Item-class. Like this:

```
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name desc:(NSString *)desc image:(UIImage *)image
{
    if((self = [super init]))
    {
        self.data = [[Item alloc]initWithName: name desc: desc];
        self.image = image;

    }

    return self;
}
```

In Appdelegate I create my objects like this (later on i will get the data from a server)

```
Item *item1 = [[ItemDoc alloc] initWithName:@"Name" desc:@"NameDescription" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"item.png"]];

Item *item2 = [[ItemDoc alloc] initWithName:@"Name2" desc:@"NameDescription2" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"item2.png"]];

NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: item1, item2, nil];
```

Now I can use this in my views to get the right information about the model objects, but I want to store more than one image in every Item. I'm not sure how to do this in a good way? Please help!

Comment: How about using an `NSArray` instead?

Comment: First of all why have you made two models, this can be done in a single model class.and as far as I have understood u will be having multiple images for a data set, so you can use an array of images i.e a array containing image objects. Or there is something else you are looking for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be achieved by creating the array of the images like:

```
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name desc:(NSString *)desc images:(NSMutableArray *)_imageArray
{
    if((self = [super init]))
    {
        self.data = [[Item alloc]initWithName: name desc: desc];
        self.imageArray = _imageArray;

    }

    return self;
}
```

for invoking  this just add all the UIImages into the array and init object with the array.

Comment: Ok, and how am I suppose to display the images in my view, if I put them in one array in my model, and then in another array called items in Appdelegate? Now I can reach them directly by self.detailItem.image

Comment: @JoSmith:sorry I cant understand your problem ? above solution will work at least for storing multiple images into the array.

Comment: If you want to access the image, then `self.detailItem.imageArray[yourIndex]`

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try this. Why I'm getting confused aswell is because I'm suppose to "lock" the images, so that the user of the application can unlock them to view them bigger. Then I need to store some kind of data in my model - which image is locked, and which image is unlocked.